# Error; cannot find symbol; Symbol: variable super

Tags: java, class, variables, symbols

I am working on 3 programs that contain the classes CarRental.java, LuxuryCarRental.java, and UseCarRental.java, On my LuxuryCarRental.java, I keep getting the error, Error; cannot find symbol; Symbol: variable super for the class, here is my program, I'm relatively new to Java, so please be detailed! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class LuxuryCarRental extends CarRental{

private boolean chauffeur;
private double dailyChauffeurFee;


public LuxuryCarRental(String renterName, int renterZip, String sizeOfCar,int rentalDays, boolean chauffeur) {
    super(renterName, renterZip, sizeOfCar, rentalDays);
    this.chauffeur = chauffeur;
}


public void display(){

    super.dailyRentalFee = 79.99;


    this.dailyChauffeurFee = 0;
    if(chauffeur){
        this.dailyChauffeurFee = 200;
    }


    super.totalRentalFee = super.dailyRentalFee * super.getRentalDays() + this.dailyChauffeurFee * super.getRentalDays();


    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");


    System.out.println("Car Rental - Renter Name : " + super.getRenterName() + ", Renter Zip: " + super.getRenterZip() + 
            ", Rental Days : " + super.getRentalDays() + 
            ", Daily Rental Fee: " + dailyRentalFee + ", Daily Chauffer Fee: " + dailyChauffeurFee + 
            ", Total Rental Fee: " + df.format(totalRentalFee));
}

}
```

And here are all the classes from all three of my programs that correspond to each other.

```
  public class CarRental {

private String renterName;
private int renterZip;
private String sizeOfCar;
private int rentalDays;
protected double dailyRentalFee;
protected double totalRentalFee;


public class UseCarRental

public class LuxuryCarRental extends CarRental {

private boolean chauffeur;

private double dailyChauffeurFee;

public CarRental(String renterName, int renterZip, String sizeOfCar, int rentalDays)
{
    renterName = renterName;
    renterZip = renterZip;
    sizeOfCar = sizeOfCar;
    rentalDays = rentalDays;
```

And my altered code:

```
public class CarRental 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

private String renterName;
private int renterZip;
private String sizeOfCar;
private int rentalDays;
protected double dailyRentalFee;
protected double totalRentalFee;
}


public CarRental(String renterName, int renterZip, String sizeOfCar, int rentalDays)
{
    renterName = renterName;
    renterZip = renterZip;
    sizeOfCar = sizeOfCar;
    rentalDays = rentalDays;
}

 public void setDailyRentalFee(double dailyRentalFee) 

 {

 this.dailyRentalFee = dailyRentalFee;

 }

public double getDailyRentalFee() 

 {

 return dailyRentalFee;

 }


public void display(){

    if(sizeOfCar.equalsIgnoreCase("economy"))
  {
        dailyRentalFee = 29.99;         
    } 

  else if(sizeOfCar.equalsIgnoreCase("midsize"))
  {
        dailyRentalFee = 38.99;         
    } else {
        dailyRentalFee = 43.50;         
    }

    //calculates total rental fee
    this.totalRentalFee = this.dailyRentalFee * rentalDays;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    //displays output
    System.out.println("Car Rental - Renter Name : " + renterName + ", Renter Zip: " + renterZip + 
            ", Size of car: " + sizeOfCar + ", Rental Days : " + rentalDays + 
            ", Daily Rental Fee: " + dailyRentalFee + ", Total Rental Fee: " + df.format(totalRentalFee));
}


public String getRenterName() 
{
    return renterName;
}


public int getRenterZip() 
{
    return renterZip;
}


public int getRentalDays() 
{
    return rentalDays;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
super.dailyRentalFee = 79.99;
```

This doesn't work. The same goes for every other place you've used it.

I assume your class has a `private` field `dailyRentalFee`?
Make it `protected` instead. Or use `public/protected` getters and setters.

You're in a subclass which you should really view as an extension of the superclass. Everything that is available in the superclass is available in the subclass, provided you don't use `private` access but rather `protected` (available in current class and subclass) or `public` (available everywhere that has access to the current class).

Example:

```
class SuperClass {
   protected int someValue = 5;
   private int anotherValue = 10;
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
   public void doSomething() {
      someValue = 6; // I can access it because it's protected instead of private
      anotherValue = 1; // I can't access it because it's private and only accessible in the SuperClass
   }
}
```

To summarize:

- Drop the `super.X`, `super()` is used to call the constructor of the superclass
- Use `protected` or `public` access identifiers instead of `private`

Comment: If the fields are protected, you can just do `this.dailyRentalFee = 79.99` or `dailyRentalFee=79.99`. There's no need to specify that they came from `super`.

Comment: Yes @Jeroen I'm using a protected double field for my dailyRentalFee

Comment: @FlightOdyssey: while typing I realized that I never explicitly stated that. It's in there now.

Comment: Also, I get this error as well after I get rid of the *super* LuxuryCarRental.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public class LuxuryCarRental extends CarRental {
                                     ^
  symbol: class CarRental

Comment: It means your class `CarRental` is not found. Is `CarRental` defined as `public` and/or in your current namespace?

Comment: Yes, it's defined as a public class,

Comment: @JeroenVannevel now I added public void setDailyRentalFee(double dailyRentalFee) and this.dailyRentalFee = dailyRentalFee; + public double getDailyRentalFee() and return dailyRentalFee; now I'm getting error can't find symbol variable dailyRentalFee location: class LuxuryCarRental

Comment: are you sure `dailyRentalFee` is declared as `protected`?

Comment: Yes, `protected double dailyRentalFee`;

Comment: Edit your post with all the relevant classes so we have an overview.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, `super` doesn't work the way you have used it.
when you extend a class, `CarRental` in your case, you inherite all `public` and `protected` members of that class. so to use a variable of your super class, you dont have to prefix `super`, you can just use the variable as if the child class holds it. so instead of

```
super.dailyRentalFee = 79.99;
```

use

```
dailyRentalFee = 79.99;  // since dailyRentalFee is protected in class CarRental
                         // this will work
```

similarly,

```
super.totalRentalFee = super.dailyRentalFee * super.getRentalDays() + this.dailyChauffeurFee * super.getRentalDays();
```

should be written as

```
totalRentalFee = dailyRentalFee * getRentalDays() + this.dailyChauffeurFee * getRentalDays();
```

provided, the method `getRentalDays` is public in the `CarRental` class.

and about the error you mentioned in @Jeroen's answers' comments,
make sure `LuxuryCarRental` and `CarRental` are in the same `package`. To be simple,
make sure both files are in the same folder.

**EDIT:**

Your code doesn't contain a `main` method, that is why that error is produced. You should have a `main` method in your program for it to execute. That is the starting point of all java applications. so define a class with a `main` method inside and then create a `LuxuryCarRental` object and perform your computations there. for example,

```
class Sample {
  public static void main(String[] args) { //this is how all main methods would look

    LuxuryCarRental luxuryCar = new LuxuryCarRental("A",62020,"SUV",10,true);
    //call the LuxuryCarRental methods as per your coding requirements

  }
}
```

see, its simpe,

```
class CarRental {
  //CarRental code
}

class LuxuryCarRental {
  //LuxuryCarRental code
}

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LuxuryCarRental luxuryCar = new LuxuryCarRental("A",62020,"SUV",10,true);
    luxuryCar.display();
  }
}
```

Comment: now I'm getting this error when I run the file, the compiling works fine now : No Main Methods, applets, or MIDlets found in file?

Comment: (Edit - Sorry for these errors) Ugh, now it's giving me an `Illegal start of Expression` error for CarRental.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
 protected double totalRentalFee;
 ^

Comment: you may be missing a `{` or `}`. since you said, it compiled fine previously, i assume you have altered you code. repost the altered code.

Comment: your code is wrong now. the class `LuxuryCarRental` should be in a separate different file. not inside the `CarRental` class. and what is this new class `UserRental`?

Comment: There are three files that are connected to each other, `UseCarRental` `LuxuryCarRental` and `CarRental` btw, I posted the new code

Comment: And then there is a `display()` method that displays all the rental data

Comment: you cannot specify access specifiers inside the `main` method. it has to be declared at the `Class` scope.

Comment: So just move everything out of it and just have renterName = renterName;
  renterZip = renterZip;
  sizeOfCar = sizeOfCar;
  rentalDays = rentalDays;

Comment: uh.. no... create a new class, and set up a main method there. create  an object of type `LuxuryCarRental` and call your other methods from there. the main method initiates the program, learn more abt it [**here**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)...

Comment: Can you provide me an example? Visual examples help me best, thanks